# Multiple items from DropDownList with protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I'm using a spreadsheet with multiple dropdown lists. For one row, I want it to be possible to select multiple items from a DropDownList.

I'm using the code below, but the problem I have is that the functionality to select multiple items is lost when I protect the workbook.

```
> Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$G$5" Or Target.Address = "$G$6" Or Target.Address = "$G$7" Or Target.Address = "$G$8" Or Target.Address = "$G$9" Or Target.Address = "$G$10" Or Target.Address = "$G$11" Or Target.Address = "$G$12" Or Target.Address = "$G$13" Or Target.Address = "$G$14" Or Target.Address = "$G$15" Or Target.Address = "$G$16" Or Target.Address = "$G$17" Or Target.Address = "$G$18" Or Target.Address = "$G$19" Or Target.Address = "$G$20" Or Target.Address = "$G$21" Or Target.Address = "$G$22" Or Target.Address = "$G$23" Or Target.Address = "$G$24" Or Target.Address = "$G$25" Or Target.Address = "$G$26" Or Target.Address = "$G$27" Or Target.Address = "$G$28" Or Target.Address = "$G$29" Or Target.Address = "$G$30" Or Target.Address = "$G$31" Or Target.Address = "$G$32" Or Target.Address = "$G$33" Or Target.Address = "$G$34" Or Target.Address = "$G$35" Or Target.Address = "$G$36" Or Target.Address = "$G$37" Or Target.Address = "$G$38" Or Target.Address = "$G$39" Or Target.Address = "$G$40" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you able to select the cells of the range to be processed? I suppose that range "G5:G40" has all its cells `Locked = False`. Is my supposition correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not protect your worksheet with excel in-build function if you intend you execute any VBA code in future, instead, please use the following code and copy to your `ThisWorkbook` tab to protect the specific worksheet while allow VBA to be run properly:

You can replace the `sheet1`with your worksheet name.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheet1.Protect Password:="xxxx", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Sheet1.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome, as long as you can continue automation :)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your question, but one suggestion to simplify all those if’s is to use this instead:

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("G5:G40")) Is Nothing Then

Comment: Ahh, thanks - Will improve my code with this! :)